# street view and backbone variable scoping

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js

I am running into a problem in the following backbone view that renders a google street view.

The problem is that in the processSVData function, `this` is not the instance of `App.DetailStreetView`. When I `console.log(this)` inside `processSVData()`, I get the `DOMWindow` object. Therefore, when trying to access `this.panorama` I get `undefined`

```
App.DetailStreetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869085,-122.254775);
        this.panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(this.el);
    },
    render: function() {
        var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(this.latLng, 50, this.processSVData);        
    },
    processSVData: function(data, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            // calculate correct heading for POV
            //var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(data.location.latLng, this.latLng);
            this.panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
            this.panorama.setPov({
                heading: 270,
                pitch:0,
                zoom:1, 
            });
            this.panorama.setVisible(true);
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. You could use [`_.bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) to bind `processSVData` to the appropriate `this`:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'processSVData');
    //...
}
```

That will make `this` always the view inside `processSVData`.

You could also use [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) just for the callback:

```
sv.getPanoramaByLocation(this.latLng, 50, _.bind(this.processSVData, this));
```

That will ensure that `this` is the view when `this.processSVData` is called as an `sv.getPanoramzByLocation` callback. You can do similar things with [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) or [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (if you don't have to worry about browser version issues) as well.

Or you could do it by hand in the usual jQuery style:

```
var _this = this;
sv.getPanoramaByLocation(this.latLng, 50, function(data, status) {
    _this.processSVData(data, status);
});
```

The first, `_.bindAll`, would probably be the most common approach in Backbone.

Comment: Best solution since you already have underscore on the page. Use native bind though if necessary / available.

Comment: @amchang87: Underscore's `_.bindAll` is built on `_.bind` and, AFAIK, `_.bind` uses the native `Function.bind` if available.